# Autolayout is changing UIScrollView's contentOffset on rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

To experiment with autolayout and uiscrollview's I have been using [this example](https://github.com/ehuynh/ScrollViewAutoLayoutExample)

which I have edited to include 2 views in the scroll view, I have setup the autolayout constraints to position the views horizontally adjacent with their size set to fill the scroll view frame.

```
UIView *beeView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BeeView" owner:nil options:nil] firstObject];
beeView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.scrollView addSubview:beeView];
UIView *beeView2 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BeeView" owner:nil options:nil] firstObject];
beeView2.backgroundColor= [UIColor orangeColor];
beeView2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.scrollView addSubview:beeView2];

NSDictionary *views = @{@"beeView":beeView,@"beeView2":beeView2, @"scrollView":self.scrollView};
NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"height" : @200};
[self.scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[beeView(==scrollView)][beeView2(==beeView)]|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom metrics:metrics views:views]];
[self.scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[beeView(==scrollView)]|" options:kNilOptions metrics:metrics views:views]];
```

which nicely produces what I intended.

However, if the scroll view's `contentOffset` is nonzero and the device is rotated from portrait to landscape, the content offset of the scroll view is automatically set to `32px`. (see screenshot)
[image: content offset wrong]

I have tried saving `contentOffset` and setting it to this saved value when `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` is called which works but is ugly as the scroll view scrolls to a 32px offset and then back to where I want it to be.

How do I control the scroll view's `contentOffset`? Are the autolayout constraints wrong? Are there extra constraints I can add to control the `contentOffset` when resizing the view?

Comment: try changing `H:|[beeView(==scrollView)][beeView2(==beeView)]|` to `H:|-[beeView(==scrollView)]-[beeView2(==beeView)]-|`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Where the 32px comes from? Is it related to your left and right scrollView margin?

Does it keep the wrong offset every time you change page ? If that the case, you should look at your scrollView's contentInsets values.

Otherwise, what I do to manage rotation on scrollView with paging is observing the scrollView's contentSize:

First, when you load the view, add the observer:

```
[self.scrollView addObserver:self forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(contentSize)) options:0 context:nil];
```

Then, when the contentSize value change, adjust the contentOffset:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    if (object == self.scrollView && [keyPath isEqualToString:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(contentSize))]) {

        //Note that you should track your page index
        self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.pageIndex * self.scrollView.bounds.size.width, self.scrollView.contentOffset.y);

    } else {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
    }
}
```

Finally, remove the observer when you unload the scrollView:

```
[self.scrollView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(contentSize)) context:nil];
```

Comment: The 32px is just something I measured, it must be a random glitch, but the addObserve method worked perfectly thanks!

Comment: This is a good suggestion; however, note that UIKit makes no guarantees about supporting KVO. So while this approach may work now, it could potentially break in a future iOS update. An alternative would be to subclass `UIScrollView` and override `setContentSize:`. See my answer below for an example.

Answer (score 3):

After referring back to a few previous posts: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523205/uiscrollview-adjusts-contentoffset-when-contentsize-changes) & [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069258/automaticallyadjustsscrollviewinsets-not-working). It seems you might find your solution following one of these steps:

1. **Programmatically** : If your UIScrollViews' parent VC is not directly on the Nav Stack -

~**Edit**~

```
    // Without a Navigation Controller

    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;

    // With a Navigation Controller

    self.parentViewController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

2. **Interface Builder** : Attributes Inspector -> Uncheck ***Adjust Scroll View Insets*** in the Layout Properties.
3. IF ***Still Unsuccessful*** : Within the presented View Controller's `ViewWillLayoutSubviews` Method try setting each of the following UIScrollView properties:

   ```
   self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
   self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
   ```

I am guessing a combination of option 1 and 2 will work, depending on how your Navigation Stack is structured.

Comment: Thanks but I am not using any kind of navigation controller so that is not interfering with it, I assume it is some weird auto layout glitch. Setting the contentOffset to zero is not particularly useful as it will just set the scroll view back to the beginning.

Comment: @DotSlashSlash I'm just glad you were able to solve your issue with one of our answers. I am quite certain, now that I you have explained you aren't using a Navigation Controller, had you gone with `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;` in your VC it would solve the problem too.

Answer (score 2):

For iOS 11.0 and greater, the following method solves the issue for me:

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *))
{
    self.myScrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. this solved my scrollview got extra spacing when scroll or after manually set contentoffset 

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but in case it is of use to anyone - I have created a subclass of `UIScrollView` called `LMPageView` that automatically applies the necessary layout constraints and adjusts the content offset on rotation. The class is available as part of the [MarkupKit](https://github.com/gk-brown/MarkupKit) project on GitHub. Example usage (Swift):

```
// Add 3 page views
pageView.addPage(view1)
pageView.addPage(view2)
pageView.addPage(view3)

// Show the 3rd page
pageView.currentPage = 2
```

An additional example that uses markup to initialize a page view can be found here:

- [PageViewController.swift](https://github.com/gk-brown/MarkupKit/blob/master/MarkupKit-iOS/MarkupKitExamples/PageViewController.swift)
- [PageViewController.xml](https://github.com/gk-brown/MarkupKit/blob/master/MarkupKit-iOS/MarkupKitExamples/PageViewController.xml)