# UIScrollView has a different y position when seguing from different view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

Not sure how to explain this, simply when seguing from one controller the scroll view is lower on the screen than from another segue where it is correct.

Comment: can you have a demo of this??? So I'll check this out

Answer (score 1):

Set this 2 scrollview property and check it.

```
self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

Check this answer it may help you [UIScrollView adjusts contentOffset when contentSize changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523205/uiscrollview-adjusts-contentoffset-when-contentsize-changes)

Answer (score 0):

Select your view controller which has lower scroll view and unselect `Adjust Scroll View Insets`

See below image:

[image]

---

or you can do it programmatically

```
self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```